# Scala implicit type casting

Tags: scala, types, casting

I'm just beginning Scala, coming from Java.

So I know that in Scala, all things are objects, and Scala matches the longest token (source: http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaTutorial.pdf), so if i understand correctly:

```
var b = 1.+(2)
```

then b is a Double, plus and Int, which in Java would be a Double.
But when I check its type via `println(b.isInstanceOf[Int])` I see that it is an Int. Why is it not a Double like in Java?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [specification](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/01-lexical-syntax.html#floating-point-literals):

> `1.` is not a valid floating point literal because the mandatory digit after the `.` is missing.

I believe it's done like that, exactly because expressions like `1.+(2)` should be parsed as an integer `1`, method call `.`, method name `+` and method argument `(2)`.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler would treat 1 and 2 as Ints by default. You could force either one of these to be a Double using `1.toDouble` And the result (b) would be a double.

Btw - did you mean to write 1.0+2 - in which case b would be a double?